# Remove website from google search results on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

For optimization purposes, I want to remove certain blogs / websites from showing up in my google search results, I have done a little research and looked through chrome but could not come across anything. Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What happens when you insert `inurl:-blogyoudontwant.com`?

Comment: Where should I insert this?

Comment: On the search box. For example, `chrome optimization -inurl:superuser.com` will exclude results from superuser.

Comment: thank you, this is a great solution